# RAID 5 Home use?

Tags: raid, raid-5

I am looking at building a home computer in the near future. This PC will be used for video capture/editing, gaming, and will be running a fairly advanced set of hardware. My question is: Should I run a RAID array for my storage, specifically a RAID-5 array? (My OS will be on an SSD, so we are only talking about storage.) My primary goal is speed, but without the risk of losing everything that a RAID 0 array poses, so it seems that a RAID-5 array is the way to go. That being said, my research has yielded split opinions on home RAID. On the one hand, it seems it should be faster, and safer, than running a stand-alone drive (or drives). On the other hand, I have read that the speed difference at a home level will be nearly unnoticeable, and that so long as I run regular backups, there is no good reason to run RAID at the home level. So ... now I don't know what to do. Is there a right answer here? or just a lot of personal preferences?

Note: Not sure if this factors into the discussion, but my MB supports RAID-5, so it will be hardware-based from the MB.

Comment: RAID-5 on your motherboard is, in almost all cases, NOT hardware RAID-5 but instead, 'fakeRAID' or software RAID5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your primary goal is speed, RAID5 is a poor choice. RAID-1 is a far better choice. If you have enough drives, RAID-1+0 may be a good alternative.

Let's imagine you have four drives. With RAID-1+0, you'd be able to survive the death of any single drive without the loss of data, and would be able to perform reads and writes quickly. The downside is that your total capacity is only that of two drives.

With RAID-5, you can again survive the death of any single drive without the loss of data. Your reads are likely going to be nice and quick, but you pay a penalty when writing data. The upside is that you have the total capacity of three drives.

Regardless of which option you go for, you'll still need to back up your data. RAID is not a backup mechanism. If you accidentally delete your data, RAID does nothing to protect you.

I built a home NAS device and went for a 5-disk RAID-6 solution. I can survive the loss of any two drives, and have the capacity of three drives. I don't care much about the speed hit.

Comment: Storage is cheap nowadays.  RAID 0+1 is the way to go.  Especially for media heavy content.

Comment: Be aware if you're buying non-consumer hardware (ie intended for commercial use) servers are _loud_.